# How to tweak Search Web Part to open search result to new tab

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part

How to tweak Search Web Part to open /search/Pages/ result to new tab instead of redirecting it on the same page ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

If this is for a search results webpart (like results.aspx), than what I found easiest was to add a content editor at the bottom of the page and add a little jquery to achieve this. You can use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ms-srch-item-link").attr("target","_blank");
</script>
```

This jquery will target all hyperlinks that appear in the search results webpart and change their attributes to open in a new tab.

Comment: I think he means from the search box page, not for the links on the results page